# Adding Multiple Javascript files to Wordpress functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, slicknav

I have managed to add one js file to the WP functions.php and this works fine. How do I add another? e.g add classie.js to the add_my_script function? I tried to duplicate the get_template_directory_uri() but this didn't work - I feel as though the answer is staring me in the face!

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'slicknav',// name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the `wp_enqueue_script` twice:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'slicknav',
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js', 
         array('jquery') 
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'classie',
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/classie.js', 
         array('jquery') 
    );
}
```

Comment: ah I knew it would be something simple! thanks for your help!